# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Device not found

Tags: android, adb

Running the app on a real device I get the error below. No issue on emulator. During "Install", the installation fails and Android Studio no longer sees the device. If I disconnect and reconnect the device it shows up in AS again. Currently running Android Studio 3.6.3

Things I've tried:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Kill and restart adb server
- Reinstall Android Studio
- Different device, project, USB cable and USB port

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Have you enabled the usb debugging from the developer option ?

Comment: @Nik yes. AS wouldn't detect the device otherwise

Comment: I'm not sure but try to update your USB driver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting Android Studio and clearing all of its directories worked.